# how to get the most frequent items

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I am working on an application which has a large array containing lines of numbers,

```
transNum[20000][200]//this is the 2d array containing the numbers and always keep track of the line numbers
```

I am using a nested loop to look for the most frequent items. which is

```
for(int i=0/*,lineitems=0*/;i<lineCounter;i++)
  {
      for(int j=0,shows=1;j<lineitem1[i];j++)
      {
          for(int t=i+1;t<lineCounter;t++)
          {
              for(int s=0;s<lineitem1[t];s++)
              {
                  if(transNum[i][j]==transNum[t][s])
                      shows++;
              }
          }

          if(shows/lineCounter>=0.2)
          {

              freItem[i][lineitem2[i]]=transNum[i][j];
              lineitem2[i]++;
          }
      }

  }
```

when I was doing tests using small input arrays like test[200][200], this loop works fine and the computing time is acceptable, but when I try to process the array contains 12000 lines, the computing time is too long, so I am thinking if there are other ways to compute the frequent items rather than using this loop.I just ran a test on 10688 lines, and the time to get all the frequent item is 825805ms, which is way to expensive.

Comment: what is `lineCounter` and `lineitem1`?

Comment: the lineCounter is the number of the total lines of transactions. and the lineitem1 is an array record the item(which are numbers) numbers in each line.

Comment: What is max/min value of items?

Comment: See solution below. It'd be interesting to see what performance you get with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your input. If you are also inserting the data in the same code then you can count frequent items as you insert them.

---

Here is a pseudo-C solution:

```
int counts[1000000];

while(each number as n)
{
    counts[n]++;
    // then insert number into array
}
```

**EDIT #2:** Make sure, so you don't get unexpected results, to initialize all the items in the array to zero.

Comment: I used the buffered reader to read Lines of numbers from a .dat file, and then store the numbers in the 2d array

Comment: and what's the point of using this counts array, to get the number of counts I still have to scan the array with the same time as the loop thing

Comment: Yes, but by doing it at the same time as you add data you don't have to scan the array again, and it will insignificantly increase the amount of time it takes to add the data.

Comment: oh, I got the point, I'll try if it works, but I think the time will not reduce too much, thanks :)

Comment: @Thomas O: In java it will be always 0) You doesn't need initialize all items to zero.

Comment: ^As in most languages, such as Python. But unless the language defines it, or you know the array is empty (for example you used calloc) you should empty the array.

Comment: @Thomas O : In Java primitive types are automatically initialized to “empty” values. There isn't any calloc(). Welcome to java world!)

Comment: Yeah, I am actually a Java programmer. (Sometimes. I prefer C for its raw speed, but Java is easier and almost as fast.) I didn't realise this question was Java until I looked at the tags because the syntax was very C like.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind this is an O(n^2) algorithm at best and could be worse.  That means the number of operations is proportional to the count of the items squared. After a certain number of lines, performance will degrade rapidly and there's nothing you can do about it except to improve the algorithm.

Comment: yea, i know this loop thing is time consuming, the point is what other algorithm could be used to sort this out

Comment: How are you acquiring the data?  Does it change once acquired?

Comment: initially, the lines of numbers was reading from a .dat file, and I used a buffered reader to read all of the numbers into a 2d array(in order to keep track of the line numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) implementation from Google Guava project might be useful in such cases. You could store items there and then retrieve set of values with count of each occurrence.

Comment: but i have to keep track which line that the certain item appears

Comment: Then you could use Multimap and call method put(item, line number). Then you'd have ability not only to get count of each item but also values of line items.

Comment: Also TreeMultimap implementation would just allow you to set Comparator for keys in which case you could sort items by number of associated occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Gave the algorithm for this one some thought. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class NumberTotalizerTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        // Number input
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; ++i ) {
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(15);
            System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt);

            Integer tempInt = hashMap.get(randomInt);

            // Counting takes place here
            hashMap.put(randomInt, tempInt==null?1:(tempInt+1) );
        }

        // Sorting and display
        Iterator itr =  sortByValue(hashMap).iterator();

        System.out.println( "Occurences from lowest to highest:" );

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            int key = (Integer) itr.next();

            System.out.println( "Number: " + key + ", occurences: " + hashMap.get(key));
        }
    }

     public static List sortByValue(final Map m) {
        List keys = new ArrayList();
        keys.addAll(m.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Object v1 = m.get(o1);
                Object v2 = m.get(o2);
                if (v1 == null) {
                    return (v2 == null) ? 0 : 1;
                }
                else if (v1 instanceof Comparable) {
                    return ((Comparable) v1).compareTo(v2);
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        return keys;
    }
}
```